# PHPMyAdmin Mysql Error creating foreign key on <attribute> (check data types)

Tags: mysql

I've read several posts already but could not fix my problem on creating foreign keys in phpMyAdmin. I have the following two schemas:

```
CREATE TABLE `verifieduser` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `rname` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `restaurant` (
  `location` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cuisine` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `rname` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `restaurant`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`location`,`rname`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `phone` (`phone`);
```

I am trying to have the rname in the verifieduser table be a foreign key to the rname in the restaurant table. I'm not sure why it doesn't allow me to since it has the same value and I did not change the constraint to "SET NULL".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above query you have not set the `rname` as the primary key of `restaurant`, i think that is the problem. In my opinion you should have a column name `id` in `restaurant` which should be the primary key and in `verifieduser` you should have `rid` as  foriegn key to `restaurant`

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the post to indicate that I did indeed have location and rname as primary keys in restaurant table but still have that problem.

Comment: are you using CLI to create tables?

Comment: Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with the term "CLi". I am simply on phpMyAdmin under the structure tab for my table to add attributes.

Comment: ALTER TABLE `verifieduser`
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_rname
FOREIGN KEY (`rname`)
REFERENCES `restaurant`(`rname`)

it think it should be something like this

Comment: Unfortunately, I get "#1005 - Can't create table `urbanfork`.`#sql-17ec_473` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")" when I run your query.

Comment: Since you have two primary key you should have two foreign key to make a relation.
This might help you
 
ALTER TABLE `verifieduser` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_rname` FOREIGN KEY (`rname`,`location`) REFERENCES `restaurant`(`rname`,`location`)

Comment: Thanks for your help but it gives the same error. When I try to set location in verifieduser to a foreign key it works but somehow it doesn't for rname.

Comment: ALTER TABLE `verifieduser` ADD INDEX(`rname`,`location`);

ALTER TABLE `verifieduser` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`location`, `rname`) REFERENCES `db_name`.`restaurant`(`location`, `rname`);

i have tried this on my local machine and its working. It might help

Comment: Thanks! From your query, I realized I made location and rname a separate index when they should be one index. I was then able to put a foreign key constraint on them together. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`FOREIGN KEY` relationship requires two table i.e. `Parent table` & `Child table`, in which their is some column in Parent table of type `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` 
and the same matching type column in Child table.

But in your case rname`varchar(50) NOT NULL is neither`UNIQUE`nor`PRIMARY`. So make it UNIQUE` nor `PRIMARY` and try again.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the post to indicate that I did indeed have location and rname as primary keys in restaurant table but still have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to Alter table `verifieduser` and rname some key. After that, you will be able to make make it foreign key. Just run queries give below. I hope these will work for you.

```
ALTER TABLE `verifieduser` ADD PRIMARY KEY(`rname`);
```

After that add FOREIGN key

```
ALTER TABLE `restaurant`  
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`rname1` ) REFERENCES `verifieduser` (`rname` )
```